# Call Microsoft Graph API - App only unauthorized error

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to make request to the Graph API using a service with no UI. I downloaded the following sample code and followed the instructions: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/12/14/implementing-application-with-o365-graph-api-in-app-only-mode/

I successfully get an Access Token, but when using it to make a request to get organization information (required Read Directory Data access), I get 403 Unauthorized.

I have registered my app in Azure AD (where I am a co-administrator).

I have specified Microsoft Graph in the 'permissions to other applications' section, and given Read Directory Data access.

Interestingly there is a note below saying 'You are authorized to select only delegated permissions which have personal scope'. Even though I clearly did. Why? I suspect this is the source of my problem.
[image: My Azure App Management Page]
Likewise I have checked my demo app against these instructions: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only, but it makes no mention of what role in Azure you need to have.

[in this SO post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408024/getting-403-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation-when-attemptin), there is mention of still needing to Consent. I haven't found any documentation about this.

Comment: I think the note in the bottom of the "permissions to other applications" view means that you can only grant Delegated permissions, which will only give the app permissions to the currently signed in user.

Is there any error response along with the 403 Unauthorized code you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are authorized to select only delegated permissions which have personal scope

This issue is caused that the app is created by none admin and when they visit the portal then will see this message.

To grant the app-only permission to the application, we need to be the administrator of the tenant. It is different with the co-administrator. To user the **Client Credential flow**, I suggest that you contact the admin of the tenant to create an application for you. And if you were just for testing purpose, you can create a free tenant and register the application yourself.

### Update

We need the assign the **Global administrator** director role as figure below to make the application works for the **client credential flow**:
[image]

Comment: I was confused between the Azure Subscription level roles, and the actual Active Directory service roles. Co-Administrator is a subscription level role and is irrelevant for consenting an application to use Client Credential Flow. I need an administrator role within the Active Directory service resource. The question is which one...: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles  This link lists all the admin roles in Active Directory. Do you know more about AD roles? I wonder which roles will allow me to do what I want with Client Credential flow?

Comment: @SeanOB We need the **Global administrator**, please check the updates in the post.

Comment: Just to add to this solution: I was made Global Admin my my tenant administrator. I then tried registering a new app in Azure Classic. It failed. I checked Azure Portal, and the app was there! But the Owners list was empty. So something went wrong registering that app. Needless to say, Client Credential Flow failed again. I ended up creating a new MVC app implementing Authorization Code Flow, just so I could authorize with my credentials and click Accept to consent to the Application Permissions. Now Client Credentials work perfectly.

Comment: @SeanOB after you register the app on the portal, we need wait the Azure portal to complete the action. If you still have the problem to create an app on the portal, I suggest that you contact the support request from the right top corner of new portal to help resolve this issue.